# Finding even numbers in lists of lists python

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

I want to how to find even numbers from lists of lists.
The example was:

```
maximum_even_each_list_in_lol([[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]])
```

should return (maximum even numbers):

```
[2,6,0]
```

I found how to find even numbers from list, from stackoverflow:

```
def maximum_even_each_list_in_lol (lol):
    evens=[]
    for number in lol:
        if is_even(number):
            evens.append(number)
    return evens
```

but I want to know how I can make it so that it can find even numbers from each list, in list.

Comment: from where this 0 came from??

Comment: where did you get the 0 from ?

Comment: and why 4 did't turn up??

Comment: it should be [2,6,4], for even number

Comment: Perhaps for lists that contains only odd items OP wants 0 as output.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - a lesson in life is to never assume what some-one else requirements are - if they aren't clear, then ask.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 You should say that to the 3 answerers below as well otherwise they may this valuable lesson.

Comment: @Hackaholic my professor put that as return value, and also I fixed the question, it was suppose to be maximum even number. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

Though you don't say it explicitly, it seems you are looking for the maximum even number in each list within a list of lists. And from your example it seems you want the programme to add 0 if there is no even number. In that case this will work:

```
print [max(value for value in [0] + L if not value % 2) for L in list_of_lists]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build this algorithm up from the inside-out using some nice Pythonic language constructs:

```
# Function to determine if one number is even
is_even = lambda x : x%2==0

# Function to return just the even numbers of a list
just_evens = lambda x : filter(is_even, x)

# Function to return the maximum number in a list, or '0' if there is none
get_max = lambda x : max(x) if len(x) else 0

# Function to return the maximum even number of a list
max_even = lambda x : get_max(just_evens(x))

# Print out the maximum even number from each list:
map(max_even, [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]])
```

This will print out:

```
[2, 6, None]
```

Comment: For the 0 part, I don't know how, but my professor put the 0 as a return value, so I am bit confused by the question myself.

Comment: The example result in OP specification has zero in place of `None`. Otherwise I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Updated to have `0` as the default.

Answer (score 1):

[python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) takes a default value for max so if after filtering there are no even numbers we can return `0` as a default value:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]
print([max(filter(lambda x: not x % 2,x),default=0) for x in l])
[2, 6, 0]
```

Comment: Python 3.4+ to be precise. :-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yep forgot to add the link

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! **:-)**

Check what the builtin [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function does.

```
def maximum_even_each_list_in_lol (lol):
    evens=[0]  # Dirty trick to ensure that regardless of the `even` numbers
               # found, you'll always have a zero among the results.
    for number in lol:
        if is_even(number):
            evens.append(number)
    print "I found these even numbers (%s) among %s" % (evens, lol)
    return max(evens)  # Return the maximum value among the `evens` list.
results = []
for lst in [[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]:
    print "Studying %s" % lst
    results.append(maximum_even_each_list_in_lol(lst))
print "This is what I found: %s" % results
```

I added some `print` statements to help follow what the code is doing. The code above will output:

```
Studying [1, 2, 3]
I found these even numbers ([0, 2]) among [1, 2, 3]
Studying [6, 5, 4]
I found these even numbers ([0, 6, 4]) among [6, 5, 4]
Studying [5, 7, 9]
I found these even numbers ([0]) among [5, 7, 9]
This is what I found: [2, 6, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to iterate over a **list of lists**, grabbing biggest even number from each list or 0 if not even numbers were found. Here is your function then:

```
def maximum_even_each_list_in_lol(lol):
    evens = []
    for sublist in lol:
        subevens = []
        for number in sublist:
            if (not number % 2):
                subevens.append(number)
        # As I understand you want to insert 0
        # if no even numbers were found, right?
        if not subevens:
            subevens = [0]
        evens.append(max(subevens))
    return evens

# Testing
assert maximum_even_each_list_in_lol([[1,2,3],[6,5,4],[5,7,9]]) == [2,6,0]
```

Make sure to read about builtin [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) function :)

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
>>> [ max(x) if len(x)>0 else 0 for x in [ list(filter(lambda x:x%2==0,x)) for x in a ]]
[2, 6, 0]
```

i used lambda to check for even number, then filter to save value for true, then max if lenght of list greater then 0 else 0